# Convert images to webP using Pillow

Tags: python, webp, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert .jpg images to webp format using [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/).

I'm using the this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile).convert("RGB")
    im.save(file + ".webp", "WEBP")
```

But I get the following error on running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webp.py", line 7, in <module>
    im.save(file + ".webp", "WEBP")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1444, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()] # unknown format
KeyError: 'WEBP'
```

Kindly help me fixing it. I have installed `libwebp-dev`.

```
>>> import PIL
>>> dir(PIL)
['PILLOW_VERSION', 'VERSION', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '_plugins']
>>> PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
'2.2.1'
>>> PIL.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```

Comment: What version of Pillow are you using?

Comment: @SamMussmann I have updated the question with required info.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure to install `WEBP` dev library for your OS. For Debian/Ubuntu it's `libwebp-dev`. You may need reinstall Pillow as well. In the output of Pillow install log you should see:

```
--- WEBP support available
```

Comment: The solution had worked for me, but I forgot to accept the answer. Reinstalling `Pillow` after installing `WEBP` library was the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your same code with only one changes. You are mentioned format as "WEBP "in capital letters. Just change "webp" (lowercase) as shown here .
Your code

```
from PIL import Image
import glob, os

for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    print(file)
    im = Image.open(infile).convert("RGB")
    im.save(file + ".webp", "webp")
```

Formatting reference is given below please check it.

[image: References]

Note - We are unable to use Broken or corrupted images. In these formats (.png,.jpg,.jpeg). It will throws error. you can handle by adding below code for broken images.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Also, i checked the above code, works well Windows and Ubuntu OS (Linux)

Tested Code

```
from PIL import Image,ImageFile
import glob, os
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

for infile in glob.glob("images/*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    print(file)
    im = Image.open(infile).convert("RGB")
    im.save(file + ".webp", "webp")
```

[image: output]