# Django - Which file types does Django's image field support / not support by default?

Tags: django, file-type, django-models

I see all these posts which talk about 'how to limit Django's imagefield to only accept certain file types' but I am yet to find a list of all the file types which Django's imagefield supports / doesn't support by default.

Is there a list of file types which Django's imagefield supports / doesn't support by default? Or does Django's imagefield allow any filetype to be submitted?

(Will django allow users to upload .pdf, .psd, .doc etc. files in an imagefield or will it raise an error?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's `ImageField` requires the third-party package Pillow (or PIL, but support is deprecated). It depends on these packages to verify that a file is indeed an image. This is not dependant on the file extension, but on the content of the file itself.

If you want to know if a certain type of file is supported, you should find out which version of Pillow/PIL you are using, and check the corresponding documentation.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer. One, PIL/Pillow has terrible documentation. There are only two versions for Pillow, 1.7.8 and "latest", at ReadTheDocs. Additionally, it's not as straightforward as this: For instance, the Pillow 2.5.1 docs list `.psd` as a "read-only" format, but opening a `.psd` file in 2.4.0 results in a "cannot identify image" `IOError`.

Comment: Related to this answer, I found another answer that explains how to allow support to webp in old pillow versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861234/3377046

Answer (score 10):

Year Of My Answer: **2020**

I'm knee-deep in this same question myself and ran across some learnings I thought I'd share.

In `django.core.validators` lives a function named `get_available_image_extensions()`. Try this out.

```
from django.core import validators

validators.get_available_image_extensions()
```

Returns:

```
['blp', 'bmp', 'dib', 'bufr', 'cur', 'pcx', 'dcx', 'dds', 'ps', 'eps', 'fit',
 'fits', 'fli', 'flc', 'ftc', 'ftu', 'gbr', 'gif', 'grib', 'h5', 'hdf', 'png',
 'apng', 'jp2', 'j2k', 'jpc', 'jpf', 'jpx', 'j2c', 'icns', 'ico', 'im', 'iim',
 'tif', 'tiff', 'jfif', 'jpe', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'mpo', 'msp',
 'palm', 'pcd', 'pdf', 'pxr', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'ppm', 'pnm', 'psd', 'bw', 'rgb',
 'rgba', 'sgi', 'ras', 'tga', 'icb', 'vda', 'vst', 'webp', 'wmf', 'emf', 'xbm',
 'xpm']
```

The function itself tries to use `PIL`. Here it is in all its glory:

```
def get_available_image_extensions():
    try:
        from PIL import Image
    except ImportError:
        return []
    else:
        Image.init()
        return [ext.lower()[1:] for ext in Image.EXTENSION]
```

Related function [validate_image_file_extension(value)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#validate-image-file-extension) uses `get_available_image_extensions()` to determine the `allowed_extensions` keyword argument.

Here that function is:

```
def validate_image_file_extension(value):
    return FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=get_available_image_extensions())(value)
```

Hopefully this answers the question of:

> Is there a list of file types which Django's imagefield supports /
> doesn't support by default?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question while writing a Django app to upload images. I got a form error when trying to upload a DNG photo. The error text was:

```
Allowed extensions are: &#39;bmp, dib, gif, tif, tiff, jfif, jpe, jpg, jpeg, pbm,
pgm, ppm, pnm, png, apng, blp, bufr, cur, pcx, dcx, dds, ps, eps, fit, fits, fli, flc,
fpx, ftc, ftu, gbr, grib, h5, hdf, icns, ico, im, iim, jp2, j2k, jpc, jpf, jpx, j2c,
mic, mpg, mpeg, mpo, msp, palm, pcd, pdf, pxr, psd, bw, rgb, rgba, sgi, ras, tga, icb, 
vda, vst, webp, wmf, emf, xbm, xpm&#39;
```

After reading around SO and digging deeper, I found Pillow's documentation on image file formats [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/handbook/image-file-formats.html) (version 3.0.0).

It appears the error text is just a list of file types supported by Pillow, and hence Django. It would be nice if they listed not-supported formats.

To resolve the issue of needing to upload non-supported formats, I just used `FileField`, and in the view function the app checks the file extension to make sure it fits the list of extensions I defined (that includes DNG).