# "Not a supported image format" error with a valid png/jpg on upload attempt in wagtail admin with lambda(zappa)/django-storages

Tags: python, django, wagtail, zappa

I'm setting up a wagtail site on AWS lambda (via zappa) with django-storages where I have a page of news articles as child pages.
I currently allow an image in the news article, and testing locally, via localstack, I'm able to create an article and upload the desired image.

However, when I deploy and try to upload an image in the production environment via the "choose an image" dialog and select the image, set a title and click upload, I get the error:

```
Not a supported image format. Supported formats: GIF, JPEG, PNG, WEBP.
```

The `/admin/images/chooser/upload/` POST response is a 200 with the output:

```
{'html': '...',
 'step': 'chooser',
 'error_label': 'Server Error',
 'error_message': 'Report this error to your webmaster with the following information:',
 'tag_autocomplete_url': '/Prod/admin/tag-autocomplete/'}
```

Unfortunately, there is no client side console log, or server side log.
Any hints on where to look to debug this issue?

I suspect it's related to the `MEDIA_URL` or bucket permissions handling.  But not sure what would need to change.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

I have a custom storage class for media defined as follows:

```
class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION
    default_acl = "public-read"
    querystring_auth = True
    file_overwrite = False
```

Related bucket lambda IAM role permissions:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{mybucket}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{mybucket}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

On the server side (lambda) there is nothing of notice...

```
[DEBUG] 2020-08-04T02:01:48.341Z da40e0a9f Importing XVThumbImagePlugin
(lots of Plugin import messages) 
...
[INFO]  2020-08-04T02:01:48.457Z    da40e0a9    106.167.141.139 - - [04/Aug/2020:02:01:48 +0000] "POST /admin/images/chooser/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5807 "https://{APIID}.execute-api.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/Prod/admin/pages/5/edit/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/83.0.4103.61 Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36" 0/570.149
```

I've been poking around the wagtail code to see if I can find where the validation is failing, and dropping in some prints, etc... but I can't seem to find where this POST 200 response is coming from.

This seemed like the place, but even raising exceptions here didn't seem to hit this code...

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/images/fields.py#L59-L64

Ok, after debug print forced into place, I've found that the error occurs in the django ImageField validation process on Image.open() attempt, resulting in the error:

> ('cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f66fc834590>',)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Which file types does Django's image field support / not support by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727697/django-which-file-types-does-djangos-image-field-support-not-support-by-def)

Comment: I don't think so.  I can't reproduce the issue locally, so I don't think it's an ImageField related issue.

Comment: Although it could be a PIL on lambda issue...

Comment: I've traced the issue down to the parent class ext validation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/validators/#validate_image_file_extension which seems to be performed via pillow... so likely a pillow on lambda or read error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as it was working locally, it turned out to be an APIGateway configuration issue.

This resolved it:

1. Add `multipart/form-data` to API Gateway Settings under Binary Media Types
2. In proxy "Method Request", "HTTP Request Headers" add "Accept" and "Content-Type"
3. RE-DEPLOY API