# How to convert UIImage to data that Django understands

Tags: swift, django, uiimage, alamofire

It may seem like a stupid question, but I have a problem with UIImage.
My app communicates with my Django server, and for that, I'm using Alamofire. I need to pass an image, but I don't know how to convert UIImage to appropriate data so that the server can understand.
My code currently looks like this:

```
let param = ["image": image] // <- 'image' is a UIImage
AF.request(method: .post, parameters: param) // and so on
```

The server says the form is invalid. For my server, I'm using a form looks like this:

```
class UploadImageForScanForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

How can I convert a UIImage to an appropriate data format so that my Django server can understand it and do its work with it?

Comment: What can your Django server understand?

Comment: @Sweeper, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727697/django-which-file-types-does-djangos-image-field-support-not-support-by-def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a "form", I'd imagine that you are supposed to send a multipart form with the image in it using the POST method, rather than a GET request.

```
let image = // get your UIImage in some way
guard let png = image.pngData() else {
    // there is no PNG representation for the UIImage
    // you can also try jpegData
    return 
}

AF.upload(multipartFormData: { form in
    form.append(png, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
}, to: someURL)
    // and then you can get the response in whatever way you like
    .responseFoo { response in
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll take a look at that.