# how to convert a gif image to webp in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

how to convert a gif image to webp in python, keeping it's animation.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.gif')
im.save('test.webp', 'webp', save_all=True)
```

get `KeyError`, is there any python solution?

Comment: May be useful, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860639/convert-images-to-webp-using-pillow

Comment: @manvi77 saddly, it's not. I want to get an animate image in webp. That got just the first frame of the gif image.

Comment: I don't think Pillow supports animated webp but please show the full stack trace.

Comment: @zephor Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @JeruLuke not yet

Comment: @zephor Did you go through the answer? Try installing the latest libwebp library

Answer (score 1):

I just skimmed through the [documentation for PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#webp), which says clearly that `webp` format is supported. It however comes with a condition. The page states **Only supported if the system webp library was built with webpmux support.**

In order to continue, you will have to install the latest **libwebp** library for your corresponding OS. It is recommended to work with it provided you have Debian/Ubuntu OS. There are plenty of resources available on the net to help you.

You may have to reinstall PIL as well

Here is a related thread I came across [GITHUB thread](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1502#issuecomment-150771825)